# Using OGNL inside OGNL is Struts2 tags

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have an iterator tag that creates both < s:url > and < sj:a > tags, being the former the href to be accessed by the latter. Here is the code:

```
<s:iterator value="areas">
    <s:url id="show_element_%{id_element}_url" action="some_action">
        <s:param name="id_current_element" value="%{id_element}" />
    </s:url>
    <sj:a href="%{show_element_?_url}" targets="...">...</sj:a>
</s:iterator>
```

Problem is, how can I get the id given to the url in the attribute href of the < sj:a >? Notice that I need to use OGNL to get the complete id of the url, but I'm already using OGNL to associate the url with the anchor tag, so, should I use OGNL inside OGNL? How can i achieve that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. There is no need to give every url a different id. Being that the case, the code is rather straightforward:

```
<s:iterator value="areas">
    <s:url id="show_element_url" action="some_action">
        <s:param name="id_current_element" value="%{id_element}" />
    </s:url>
    <sj:a href="%{show_element_url}" targets="...">...</sj:a>
</s:iterator>
```

Thanks.